# Debugging possible hardware freezing

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze

I'm running Windows 7 and at random time the laptop freezes with a black screen.
In the Event Viewer I saw only the "kernel-power" error and it is generated by me while pressing the power buttor to force the shutdown of the laptop. Nothing else.

Is there a way, for example use a live distro, to see a better log error?

Comment: at the freeze, press the CAPS LOCK key and look if the light on the keyboard toggles or not. if the light toggles, it is a software issue, if not you have a HW issue.

Comment: Here we are: the freeze came again. I press the CAPS LOCK but the light doesn't toggle. Same thing with Fn+F1,F2... Now that I know that it is a hardware problem how can I debug it? I have ran different diagnostic tool for memory, for HDD, for video card but everything seems ok. Maybe can I use linux distro that has a more verbose error log?

Comment: run CPU-Z and look in the memory and SPD tab and check that the RAM timings match.

Comment: Everything seems ok. Screenshot: [1](http://i.imgur.com/4LDipaj.jpg)-[2](http://i.imgur.com/DLCe8jS.jpg)-[3](http://i.imgur.com/z0nHiUn.jpg). If i'm not wrong timings in SPD tab say the frequency that should be and in the Memory tab I have the actual timings of my RAM. Is that right?

Comment: picture 1 shows a **command rate** of 1. This ca cause issues. Go into the bIOS/UEFI and change it to 2.

Comment: First of all, thanks for help. Unfortunately the bios doens't have the option to change that. Now, waiting for other possible advices, I'm running several times the memory diagnostic tool (the service manual of the laptop says that for intermittent problems it is recommended to run at least 10 (!) times the diagnostic tools - but for now all tests seem ok)

Comment: is the power adapter stable? Look if tools like HWiNFO can monitor the voltages and if yes, look for drops.

Comment: I checked and everything seems ok - [pic](http://i.imgur.com/LxX3LUO.jpg). I connected another power supply and the voltage seems stable too. It's hard to look if there are drops, because 1) you have to always look the screen on the HWMonitor app and 2) if you take your eye off it for one second and the freeze happens you haven't get the drop.Howerver this problem is becoming very hard to find in fact it is very very discontinuos. I can power on and use the PC 10+ times and nothing happens. But all at once the system freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Some [live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD)s that provide memory diagnostic capabilities:

[MemTest86](http://www.memtest86.com/)

[memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)

[DocMemory](http://www.docmemory.com/page/products/doc/docinfo.asp) - you will have to register to download the free memory diagnostic utility

You can also find memtest86 and memtest86+ as well as other memory diagnostic utilities and other hardware test tools, including hard disk drive and processor test tools, on the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) also includes memtest86+ as well as many other diagnostic tools (look in the Testing Tools section).

If the problem is intermittent, I'd suggest running a memory test for at least an hour, not just for one pass. I often let a test run overnight in such cases.

The above diagnostic tools are free. [QuickTech Professional](http://uxd.com/software-diagnostics.shtml) is a commercial tool that has been useful for me.

[Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) is a "free open source software that monitors temperature sensors, fan speeds, voltages, load and clock speeds of a computer" that you could also use to monitor the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested the hardware with similiar tools on Windows and everything seems ok. I'll try with your advice: run it for hours.